# How can I change an index defined on a table?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I have an index defined like

```
add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
```

Is there any way to change this index to drop the UNIQUE constraint, something like 'change_index'?
Or is it the only way to drop the index and add it again without the UNIQUE constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different index types are typically implemented in very different ways in the database you are using. A primary index is very different from any secondary index. And unique indexes are typically different from search indexes to facilitate their primary use case: to *quickly* determine if a value is already present in a column vs. allowing efficient searches.

As such, (depending on your DBMS) you can't change an existing index. You safest bet in any case is to drop the index and create a new one. This can be done during live operations. There is no need to shutdown neither the database nor your rails app.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "change_index" in migrations so you can do:

`remove_index :users, :email`

`add_index :users, :email, :unique => false`

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in two steps - first creating the index you need in one migration file and dropping the existing one in another.

First file:

```
class AddNewIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    add_index(
      :users,
      :email,
      unique: false,
      name: "index_non_unique_emails_on_users",
      algorithm: :concurrently
    )
  end
end
```

Second file:

```
class DropOldListCIndexFromPushLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index(
      :users,
      name: <existing unique index name> # have a look in db/schema.rb
    ) if index_exists?(:users, name: "index_non_unique_emails_on_users")
  end
end
```

Please have a look at [Zero Downtime Migrations' readme](https://github.com/LendingHome/zero_downtime_migrations) if you're new to safe migrations.